# $R^iF(X)= 0$ for $i \ge $1, when $X$ is injective.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with enough injective objects, $\mathcal{B}$ an abelian category, and $\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ a left-exact functor.

Since $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injective objects, every object $X \in \mathcal{A}$ admits  an injective resolution
$$
0 \to X \to I^0 \to I^1 \to \dots.
$$

Now if $X$ is itself injective why is it that for the right derived functors we have $$R^iF(X)= 0, \quad i \ge 1?$$

Does the proof of this need the fact that different choices of injective resolutions of objects in $\mathcal{A}$ yield isomorphic derived functors?

Answer (score 2):

Note that derived functors are defined up to a choice of injective resolutions, so if you write "the derived functors", you implicitly mean that your derived functors are independent of the choice of the injective resolution. This independence result is often known as the **homotopy comparison lemma**, which can be found in any book on homological algebra. So in particular, if $X$ is injective then $0 \to X \to X \to 0$ is a resolution, you remove the zero degree term and apply $F$ to get $0 \to F(X) \to 0$, this complex has all cohomology of degree $\geq 1$ zero, which are $R^i F(X)$ for $i \geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm somewhat confused with the indices, why is it that $i \ge 1$? What even is the zeroth cohomology in this case? @alexey-do

Comment: @Tepes, it is just $F(X)$. Cohomology (or homology) are just kernel/image.